# Les fleuves en France

Tags: culture

Je me doute qu’il n’y a que la Garonne (le plus court fleuve) et Le Rhin ( il est bien puissant)
Mais quant au Rhône? J’ai entendu et même cherché sur internet , c’est le plus puissant mais on ne le sert pas pour l’électricité?

Comment: Cette question n'est pas une question de langue, elle ne rentre pas dans le cadre des [questions qu'on peut poser sur le site](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). [Liste](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_fleuves_de_France) des fleuves en France. La Garonne n'est pas le plus court, (au moins la Dordogne est plus courte). Il y a des installations hydroélectriques sur le Rhône. D'après [cette carte](https://europeanwater.org/fr/ressources/rapports-et-publications/746-barrages-et-hydroelectricite-du-rhone) il y aurait 19 centrales hydroélectriques sur le Rhône.

Comment: Merci beaucoup je m’excuse de n’avoir pas fait attention.

Comment: Le plus court fleuve de France est la [Veules](https://www.francebleu.fr/le-plus-petit-fleuve-de-france-est-encore-plus-petit-1376472360) 1149 m

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about French language.

Comment: @Toto Avec un [moulin](http://www.moulinsnormandspicards.org/moulin-des-aieux.html) sur un chemin des Champs Élysées !

Answer (score 1):

En français, un fleuve par définition se jette dans la mer ou l'océan, sinon c'est une rivière. Par exemple l'Adour et la Somme sont des fleuves alors que le Lot ou la Saône sont des rivières. On apprend à l'école qu'il y a quatre "grands" fleuves en France, par ordre de longueur: la Loire, le Rhône, la Seine et la Garonne.

Comment: Petite correction: La [Seine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seine) 774,76 km, La [Garonne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garonne)  647 km.

Comment: @Toto Merci c'est corrigé